# Button onclick result: "'Function' is not defined" in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, codesandbox

I am using CodeSandbox to write up a localized access point for my social media (just to have fun with the Vanilla parcel pack they have). Now, I have my buttons calling separate functions, but when I select a button, the error "`Function` is not defined"

My functions for the buttons are stored in a separate file than the regular JavaScript.

I have looked on W3Schools to see how this is done. Several times I tried even putting the function within the HTML page itself to see if that helps; however, the error still appeared.

Below is an HTML example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="sShowFunction()">
          Discord Status
        </button>
        <br />
        <p id="dshow">Reveal Discord Status</p>
        <script src="extras/buttons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is the js function:

```
function sShowFunction() {
  document.getElementById("dshow").innerHTML = `
  <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=<server id>&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  `;
}
```

I expect the output when I press the button to display the discord widget. Instead, I produce the aforementioned error. My best guess is that I am missing a piece of code to call the function.
In the console, I receive this error:
`sShowFunction' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)`

Comment: post codesandbox link

Comment: depend where you have declare  the function  .. could be is not accessible .. from the html level

Comment: That's not an error, it's a lint warning: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

Comment: CodeSandbox link: https://ql80k.codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depend where you have declare the function .. could be is not accessible .. from the html level

be sure your js code is inside a valid  scritpt tag

```
<script>
  function sShowFunction() {
     document.getElementById("dshow").innerHTML = '
       <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=<server id>&theme=dark" 
     width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  ';
  }
</script>
```

and don't use backtics for wrap string  .. use quote

Comment: I declare the function for the button from a separate file called `extras/buttons.js`. The backticks are so (what I assume) Code Sandbox can recognize the iframe section. I'll try what you suggest to see if that works

Comment: Ok so I put the script within the HTML file and it worked. That bugs me now because it seems that I cannot call that function from a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you put a class/id in the button and then use listener like this:

```
<button type="button" id="sShowFunction">
          Discord Status
</button>
<br />
<p id="dshow">Reveal Discord Status</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("sShowFunction").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("dshow").innerHTML = `
       <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=<server id>&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    `;
}
</script>
```

Also, you are maybe getting this error from inside the iframe.

Can't you post some photo of the error on developer console or provide more about your javascript?

Comment: I get the same error in the console: `(index):27 Uncaught ReferenceError: sShowFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):27)
onclick @ (index):27`

Comment: But that does not make sense, you're not using sShowFunction as a function.

Comment: Try to reload the document with Shift + F5

Comment: Shift + F5 resulted in no change. I still get the error. I am using sShowFunction as a call for the function in the JavaScript. In this case, it is the JS that reveals the iframe using innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

See if chrome>console>network request for buttons.js is ok (not red) because code provided by you works in my local machine

Comment: Works how? meaning you receive no red when running the code?

Comment: no when I running the code I receive black request (red means error)

Answer (score 0):

So what we need to do is **create a static template** on codesandbox. For doing this, go to the settings option on the left sidebar and then click on create **sandbox.config.json**. Then on this, select under template -> **static** option as shown in the image below.
[image]

To **save time**, you can **fork this one** - https://codesandbox.io/s/static-vanilla-js-template-qzxfi

A **detailed solution** is mentioned on this Github issue - https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1502#issuecomment-584886419